# Calculating iso tile co-ordinates for a TMX map when zoomed on a CCLayerPanZoom control

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayerpanzoom

I'm working on some code to place isometric CCTMXTiledMap onto a CCLayerPanZoom control and then convert a touch location into ISO tilemap co-ordinates. This all works perfectly well for me, so long as the scale of the CClayerPanZoom is 1 (i.e. if I don't zoom in or zoom out). I can pan the map around and still calculate the correct iso tile co-oridinates. However, as soon as I zoom the tiled map in or out the iso cordinates returned by my code are completely wrong. Please see below for my code to calculate the iso co-ordinates from the touch location.

```
-(CGPoint) tilePosFromLocation:(CGPoint)location tileMap:(CCTMXTiledMap*)thisTileMap panZoom:(CCLayerPanZoom*)thisPanZoom
{   
float midScale = (thisPanZoom.minScale + thisPanZoom.maxScale) / 2.0;

float newScale = (thisPanZoom.scale <= midScale) ? thisPanZoom.maxScale : thisPanZoom.minScale;
if (thisPanZoom.scale < 1)
{        
    newScale = newScale + thisPanZoom.scale;
}
else
{
    newScale = newScale - thisPanZoom.scale;
}

CGFloat deltaX = (location.x  - thisPanZoom.anchorPoint.x * (thisPanZoom.contentSize.width / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) ) * (newScale);
CGFloat deltaY = (location.y  - thisPanZoom.anchorPoint.y * (thisPanZoom.contentSize.height / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) ) * (newScale);

CGPoint position = ccp((thisPanZoom.position.x - deltaX) , (thisPanZoom.position.y - deltaY) );

float halfMapWidth = thisTileMap.mapSize.width * 0.5f;
float mapHeight = thisTileMap.mapSize.height;
float tileWidth = thisTileMap.tileSize.width / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * newScale;
float tileHeight = thisTileMap.tileSize.height / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * newScale;

CGPoint tilePosDiv = CGPointMake(position.x / tileWidth, position.y / tileHeight );
float inverseTileY = tilePosDiv.y - (mapHeight * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) * newScale; //mapHeight + tilePosDiv.y;

float posX = (int)(tilePosDiv.y - tilePosDiv.x + halfMapWidth);
float posY = (int)(inverseTileY + tilePosDiv.x - halfMapWidth + mapHeight);


// make sure coordinates are within isomap bounds
posX = MAX(0, posX);
posX = MIN(thisTileMap.mapSize.width - 1, posX);
posY = MAX(0, posY);
posY = MIN(thisTileMap.mapSize.height - 1, posY);

return CGPointMake(posX, posY);
}
```

Can anyone offer any insight into where I'm going wrong with this?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: try multiplying the touch location coordinates with the layer's scale factor

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'm already doing that where I calculate the deltaX and deltaY values. However, I did try your suggestion and multiplied the location.x and location.y values by newScale but that didn't work either.

Comment: Multiply ONLY tileWidth and tileHeight with the newScale factor...nothing else...let me know if it works